# Does RDF actually contains data?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, semantics, google-knowledge-graph

I am very new to semantics technologies and recently started reading through various web sources. What I understood after reading was RDF contains data. But when I started working on a `Web Semantics` tool by [cambridge semantics](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/) i.e. `Anzo Enterprise`. I realized its getting data from various data sources. and every time it takes real time data. We also have to create`.trig`  files and import it to Anzo application.

I don't understand if data is being captured at real time, what does these `.trig` files contains. Are these files `RDF` or `OWL`. And If these trig files contains data then how will data get updated in them.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. RDF is a data format - it does not "contain" data, it is way to model/write down data.

Comment: I was unsure regarding this. That is why I put up this question over forum. In few rdf examples I saw URI were referring directly to data like `foaf/<name of person>`  at other examples they were referring to a class of data like `foaf`.

Answer (score 1):

RDF can be used to write data, i.e., assertions about individuals (such as names for people, for example) and to write axioms about the structure of a knowledge base (such as classes ands subclasses, property ranges, property domains, and so on).

Different data sources can access RDF files (e.g., .trig files) or be totally dynamic - meaning they're built on the fly from some other source of data - databases, remote URLs) - this is dependent on the specific data source, and not a characteristic of RDF itself.

In short, if by data you refer to assertions about individuals (what in OWL is known as an ABox), this data can be contained in the RDF itself, but this is simply how it's presented to code using it. It can either exist statically in files, or built dynamically (e.g., as an answer to a SPARQL query.